# Why Clipboard.SetText doesn't work?

Tags: c#, clipboard

I have problem with copy some text to clipboard.
My code looks like this:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    namespace namespace
    {
        public class Class1
        {
            public void Method1()
            {
                Clipboard.SetText("some text");
            }
        }
}
```

but on  line `Clipboard.SetText("...");`
There is error message

> CS0103 The name 'Clipboard' does not exist in the current context

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Sinatr - You`re right. I take that back. Comment removed.

Comment: Does `namespace namespace` rings a bell?

Comment: @Sinatr then the error would have been different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Clipboard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) class is in the `PresentationCore` assembly, so you need to add a reference to `PresentationCore.dll` and use the appropriate namespace:

```
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText("some text");
```

Or (as you are already doing):

```
using System.Windows;
.
.
.
Clipboard.SetText("some text");
```